# Trying to change the start-up sound

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm trying to change my startup sound, however i'm not getting it to work.
It does play the default sound, however i'm having no luck getting it to play a different sound.

Things I have tried:

- changing the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsUnlock, WindowsLogoff and WindowsLogon keys
- Changing the sounds in the sound menu
- Turned off fast Startup
- Replacing the Windows Startup.wav files in the windows directory (made a backup of them first)

I have been successful in changing my shutdown sound, my startup sound just won't change.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method to change the log-on sound up to Windows 10 was:

- Use `regedit` to navigate to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsLogon`
- Double-click `ExcludeFromCPL` and set it to zero (`0`),
  for showing up in the following applet
- Run from the Start menu the applet *Change System Sounds*
- Scroll down and click on *Windows Log-on*
- Click *Browse* and position to the replacement `.wav` sound file
- Click OK all the way through.

In Windows 10, Microsoft has decided to disable it, because it caused problems
with Fast Boot. So were disabled the sounds for
'Exit Windows', 'Windows Logon' and 'Windows Logoff'.

To re-enable these sounds, one now needs to create these events.

The first step is to create a `.vbs` file to play the sound:

```
Set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
set oSpFileStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
oSpFileStream.Open "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logon.wav"
oVoice.SpeakStream oSpFileStream
oSpFileStream.Close
```

Change the above default sound file, `C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logon.wav`,
to any other `.wav` file if required.

To create the event, start the Task Scheduler and:

- Click on *Create Task...*
- Give the task some meaningful name like "Play logon sound"
- Set the option *Configure for:* to Windows 10
- In the *Triggers* tab click on *New...*
- Set *Begin the task:* to "At log on" and press OK
- In the *Actions* tab click *New...*
- Set *Action* to "Start a program"
- As *Program* enter `wscript.exe`
- In *Add arguments (optional):* enter the full path to the `.vbs` file
- Press OK
- In the *Conditions* tab disable the option "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power"
- Click OK to create the scheduled task.

For more details with screenshots see the article
[How to Play the Logon Sound in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/play-logon-sound-windows-10/).

Comment: tried it and it didn't work, i already changed the sounds but the default one keeps playing when i reboot.

Comment: You are right - it's more complicated in Windows 10.